# When should we bind multiple clients in the zmq ROUTER socket

Tags: python, zeromq

Consider the sample ZMQ broker program below:

```
def startBroker ():
# Prepare our context and sockets
    context = zmq.Context()
    frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
    backend = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
    frontend.bind("tcp://*:5555")
    frontend.bind("tcp://*:5558")
    backend.bind("tcp://*:5556")
    backend.bind("tcp://*:5557")

    # Initialize poll set
    poller = zmq.Poller()
    poller.register(frontend, zmq.POLLIN)
    poller.register(backend, zmq.POLLIN)

    # Switch messages between sockets
    while True:
        socks = dict(poller.poll())

    if socks.get(frontend) == zmq.POLLIN:
        message = frontend.recv_multipart()
        backend.send_multipart(message)

    if socks.get(backend) == zmq.POLLIN:
        message = backend.recv_multipart()
        frontend.send_multipart(message)
```

What are the parameters must be considered by an developer to bind multiple sockets to the front end ?

> frontend.bind("tcp://*:5555")

**How many request can one socket in the ROUTER process ?**

**Is it ideal to bind multiple sockets to frontend ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as though there might be a misunderstanding about what your code is doing.

```
frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
```

That code creates a `ROUTER` socket and stores it in `frontend`.  `frontend` is now a `ROUTER` socket.

```
frontend.bind("tcp://*:5555")
frontend.bind("tcp://*:5558")
```

That code `bind()`s that single socket onto multiple endpoints.  I thought there was different semantics to do so within a single call to `bind()`, but [this link](http://lists.zeromq.org/pipermail/zeromq-dev/2010-September/006287.html) appears to indicate that you do it the way you've done it here.

You *cannot* bind multiple sockets to the *same* endpoint. You'll get an error that that address is in use.  In your case, *if* you truly needed two sockets, you would have to do something like the following, the specifics would depend heavily on your particular use case:

```
context = zmq.Context()
frontend1 = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
frontend2 = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
backend1 = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
backend2 = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
frontend1.bind("tcp://*:5555")
frontend2.bind("tcp://*:5558")
backend1.bind("tcp://*:5556")
backend2.bind("tcp://*:5557")
```

... however, I wouldn't recommend that without running into a specific problem that can't be solved on a single socket (which, I suppose, is what your question is here in the first place - answered at the bottom).

Before I get into that, your broker here is acting as a simple forwarding proxy, and there are more direct ZMQ semantics to accomplish that with `zmq_proxy()`, you can see the example [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/py:msgqueue), relevant bits copied here:

```
context = zmq.Context()

# Socket facing clients
frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)
frontend.bind("tcp://*:5559")

# Socket facing services
backend  = context.socket(zmq.DEALER)
backend.bind("tcp://*:5560")

zmq.proxy(frontend, backend)

# We never get here…
frontend.close()
backend.close()
context.term()
```

... that code accomplishes the *same thing* that your code does, in a more "ZMQ appropriate" way.  This sample code came from the [ZMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all), there are tons of examples with Python code throughout that guide, I highly suggest you read it.

---

SO, here's the answer to the question (paraphrased) "When should a developer choose to use more than one socket to serve a specific service need":

Very rarely.  A single ZMQ socket can, theoretically, handle *millions* of messages a second.  Message size matters, of course, you're limited by the bandwidth of your connection and moving stuff around in memory isn't free, but theoretically a single ZMQ socket can handle most general workloads.  If you want to load balance, you'll typically spin up a new process, perhaps on a whole separate host, but it may work spinning up a second socket within the same process, just depends on what your chokepoint is - it's likely to be some other system resource before it's the ZMQ socket, but that determination will come from the specifics of your application.

So, in general, start with a single socket and squeeze as much as you can out of it, and when you see that performance could be improved by scaling horizontally, look at the specifics of your situation to determine the best way to do that.